# Twitter REST API: Cannot fetch mentions from a specific user via GET statuses/mentions_timeline

Tags: rest, twitter

In my twitter bot, I'm implementing some auto reply function, using twitter REST API: [GET statuses/mentions_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline).

But strangely I could never get the mentions sent from an specific user.
(I could fetch the mentions sent from other than the user)

The specific user is..

- Not a protected user
- Follower.
- Followed by the bot
- Not muted by the bot
- Not blocked by the bot
- made 130 days ago (too new???)
- Following 41
- Followed by 11

I don't have any other idea that causes this strange behavior.

Does anyone know what the matter is?

What **possibly** causes failing to fetch the mentions from the specific user?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly I could fetch tweets from the user.
Maybe it was temporal issue of the twitter API.